# How to print a value/values that is in the next line of the pattern matched using sed

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed

I am trying to read a file matching a pattern but the values I want are in the next consecutive lines and are dynamic (meaning different number of values for different files). Can someone help me in achieving this logic using sed?

file 1:

```
hosts:
 - abc
 - def
```

file 2:

```
hosts:
 - abc
 - def
 - ghi
```

I want to get the values of hosts using sed. 
sed of File 1 should return

```
 - abc
 - def
```

and sed of file2 should return

```
 - abc
 - def
 - ghi
```

Thanks.

Comment: file 1:

hosts: 
- abc
 - def

file 2:

hosts: 
- abc 
- def 
- ghi

sed of File 1 should return 
- abc 
- def 
and sed of file2 should return 
- abc 
- def 
- ghi

Comment: use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as code/data/output. Good luck.

Comment: how do you understand that the list of hosts end?  what is in the following line?

Comment: They end with a blank line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print lines between `hosts` and next blank line(as mentioned in comments):

```
sed '/^hosts/,/^$/{//d;}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file1 | tail -n+2
```

will do it if you just have a one line header and then the hosts.

Comment: thanks for your quick response. Actually the values for the hosts are in next consecutive lines and not in same line as hosts (so abc is in a new line, def is in a new line so on and so forth..). I have no idea why stackoverflow is posting the values in the same line as hosts. And also I mentioned two files just to give an example. I want just the values of hosts as is from the file using sed or some other tool.

Comment: this looks like a yaml file.

Comment: you might be better off using a yaml parsing tool, like python and pyyaml

Comment: if hosts: is the first thing in the file, and there is only entries with - in front, you can simply `cat file1 file2 | grep -v "hosts:"`

Comment: or even `cat file1 | tail -n+2`

Comment: yaml parsing tool seems to help but I wanted to use sed to maintain uniformity in my script. Answer given by @SLePort matched the criteria that I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little clumsy, but it appears to work:

```
sed -n -e ':a' -e '/\n$/{s/hosts:\n//; p;}' -e '/hosts/N' -e '/hosts/ b a' filename
```